# Integration NPM module into VUE2 typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, vue.js

I want install the NPM module into VUE2 typescript.

Module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/coingate-api

Code to implement:

```
var Client = require('coingate-api').Client;
var client = new Client({'mode': staging || production, 'appId': myappid, 'apiKey': mykey, 'apiSecret': mysecret});
client.createOrder(order);
```

My transformation this code into VUE2 is:

```
import { Client } from 'coingate-api'
...
var client = new Client({'mode': this.apiPayGateway, 'appId': this.apiPayId, 'apiKey': this.apiPayKey, 'apiSecret': this.apiPaySecret})
client.createOrder(this.getOrder())
```

Seems the first code is the issue.

This give me errors, that I need install additional modules:

```
These dependencies were not found:
* fs in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
* net in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js, ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js and 1 other
* tls in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js, ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
```

Installation with npm install --save fs net tls make no difference.

Is my code in typescript ok? Probably do you think is the module from NPM working?

Comment: `fs` s a node only module, they don't work inside the browser, since browsers don't have a file system

Comment: The dependencies in module are: @types/q, @types/request, moment, q, request, rxjs